# how to set ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback in web.config

Tags: c#

How do I set this in web.config file

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>true;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this;

Write your code in **Application_Start** of **Global.asax**.

It should work..!!!

**OR**

In Config file;

```
<configuration>
 <system.net>
   <settings>
     <servicePointManager
        checkCertificateName="false"
        checkCertificateRevocationList="false"         
     />
  </settings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

you can also VISIT [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsk61s76(v=vs.110).aspx) for the same.

Comment: but this returning error Only one <configSections> element allowed. It must be the first child element of the root <configuration> element  @H.Mahida

Comment: If you are using <configSections> the <system.net> element must be beneath the <configSections> Despite what the missleading error says.