# C# Visual Studio 2015: IWebProxy certificate validation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, http, ssl, proxy

I'm trying to create a C# proxy DLL that allow VS2015 Community, on my offline workstation, access to internet through a corporate HTTP proxy with authentication.

Following instruction of [this MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rido/2010/05/06/how-to-connect-to-tfs-through-authenticated-web-proxy/)  I'm able to connect VisualStudio to HTTP pages in this way:

```
namespace VSProxy
{
    public class AuthProxyModule : IWebProxy
    {   
        ICredentials crendential = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

        public ICredentials Credentials
        {
            get
            {
                return crendential;
            }
            set
            {
                crendential = value;
            }
        }

        public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (Header, Cer, Claim, SslPolicyErrors) => true;
            return new Uri("http://128.16.0.123:1234", UriKind.Absolute);
        }

        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
        {
            return host.IsLoopback;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to connect to the account authentication page for Visual Studio Community access.

So, I'm trying to validate Microsoft certificate using DLL.

There is any way can I accomplish HTTPS and certificate issue?

How can I validate the certificate in the webProxy DLL?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bypass the certificate check altogether, you could set your `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to always use a delegate which returns true:

```
var validationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
```

....

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += validationCallback;
```

I'd wrap that in a try / catch / finally and in the finally, remove the delegate (as it otherwise applies process-wide iirc):

```
finally
{
     ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= validationCallback;
}
```

UPDATE 26/03/18:
If you have control over the creation of the `HttpClient`, you can pass a `HttpClientHandler` when you construct it, with its `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` delegate set to return true. You are effectively limiting the dangerous effect of disabling SSL checking process-wide and limiting it to the use of this HttpClient. Much safer. Code:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

// Optional check to enable / disable based on config setting.
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSslCertificateCheck"] == null ||
    Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSslCertificateCheck"]) == false)
{
    handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => true
    };
}

return new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: **warnung:++ since the setting is global, it will apply to multi-threaded calls even when you turn off validation. It's better to implement specific host checks or to accept specific a certificate thumbprint. Better yet, install the cert into the windows certificate store so it's picked up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a SSL proxy certificate company gave. You just import the one into root certificate in IE(i.e. http://www.instructables.com/id/Installing-an-SSL-Certificate-in-Windows-7/, https://bto.bluecoat.com/webguides/sslv/sslva_first_steps/Content/Topics/Configure/ssl_ie_cert.htm)

Or just ignoring certificate validation via .Net config

1. [how to set ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243293/how-to-set-servicepointmanager-servercertificatevalidationcallback-in-web-config)
2. [How to stop certificate errors temporarily with WCF services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764317/how-to-stop-certificate-errors-temporarily-with-wcf-services) (OzrenTkalcecKrznaric's answer)

In case of Visual Studio 2015, the .Net config file is located at "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config".

I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` Is the main access for network certificate validation on .Net if you wish to validate a certificate you must do it here. What I suggest you is to bind the callback somewhere else than inside the `GetProxy` method. Put it where you initialize the proxy and the perform your certificate validation there.